# In Cypress tests, how do I retry a button click if an expected XHR request does not go out : waitUntil() with click XHR condition??

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, wait, cypress

At a very high level, we click a button which commands a building-control point; turns a light on or off. The click is supposed to send a POST request to the server. The issue is sometimes, the button is clicked and the POST request does not go out. The button has no functionality to indicate if it has been clicked (minor enhancement) .

For the time being, I want to work around this using Cypress plug-in [waitUntil()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) .

```
    // define routes
    cy.server();
    cy.route('POST', '\*\*/pointcommands').as('sendCommand');

    // setup checkFunction for cy.waitUntil()
    const waitForPost200 = () => cy.wait('@sendCommand', {timeout: 10000}).then(xhr => cy.wrap(xhr).its('status').should('eq', 200));

    // setup jQuery for cy.pipe()
    const click = $el => $el.click();

    // click the button
    cy.get('.marengo-ok')
      .should('be.visible')
      .pipe(click);
      // need to pass in a synchronous should() check so that the click is retried. How can we achieve this with waitUntil ?

    // wait until checkFunction waitForPost200() returns truthy
    cy.waitUntil( (): any => waitForPost200(), {
      timeout: 10000,
      interval: 1000,
      errorMsg: 'POST not sent `enter code here`within time limit'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to leverage the `cy.wait('@sendCommand')` command restoring the test in case of failure (in case the XHR call is not made).

The fastest solution that comes to my mind is the following:

```
let requestStarted = false; // will be set to true when the XHR request starts
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '\*\*/pointcommands',
  onRequest: () => (requestStarted = true)
}).as('sendCommand');

cy.get(".marengo-ok").as("button");

cy.waitUntil(() =>
    cy
    .get("@button")
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
    .then(() => requestStarted === true)
, {
  timeout: 10000,
  interval: 1000,
  errorMsg: 'POST not sent `enter code here`within time limit'
});

cy.wait("@sendCommand");
```

You can play with [a repo](https://github.com/NoriSte/wait-until-click-xhr) I prepared for you where I simulate your situation. That's the end result of the test in my repo.

[image: result screenshot]

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 7):

I think the underlying issue is that the test runner clicks on the button before an event listener gets attached. See the discussion in https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/ My advice (aside from using `waitUntil` plugin), is to use https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-pipe which provides `cy.pipe` and click the button using jQuery method

```
// cypress-pipe does not retry any Cypress commands
// so we need to click on the element using
// jQuery method "$el.click()" and not "cy.click()"
const click = $el => $el.click()

cy.get('.owl-dt-popup')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('.owl-dt-calendar-cell-content', dayRegex)
  .pipe(click)
  .should($el => {
    expect($el).to.not.be.visible
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Gleb, this was the first approach.However, it is a case where after clicking the button, there is no DOM indication of state change: the button is still clickable and the user can spam it. I entered a defect for this and meanwhile needed a way to check if XHRs went out after button click.