# 500 Server Error in Cypress tests to one of the AJAX request

Tags: ajax, drupal, cypress, wait

I'm facing an issue while working with Cypress test on a Drupal 8 based website, I'm getting a 500 server error when one of the button is clicked which invokes AJAX command, it works perfectly fine when I'm browsing the same page locally but Cypress is immediately throwing a 500 Server Error.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57705793/969092) by @NoriSte, I've tried the following code using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until `cy.waitUntil` & updated the selectors, etc., the code is attempting/clicking the button multiple times but in all the request the AJAX is getting 500.

[image: 500 Server Error]

```js
    // This will be set to true when the XHR request starts.
    let requestStarted = false
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/the-ajax-url?*',
      onRequest: () => (requestStarted = true)
    }).as('sendCommand');

    cy.get('.the-button-selector').as('button')

    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get('@button')
      .should('be.visible')
      .click({force: true})
      .then(() => requestStarted === true), {
      timeout: 20000,
      interval: 1000,
      errorMsg: 'POST not sent `enter code here` within time limit'
    })

    cy.wait('@sendCommand')
```

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to allow this AJAX request some time, so instead of quickly throwing 500 error, it loads up & works as expected.

Note: This AJAX request response in actual is approx ~1.5 MB, not sure if somehow this could be helpful.

Comment: If you comment out the server and route lines, does it work the same as it does when you run it from your browser?

Comment: No, with/without in both the cases Cypress isn't working as expected, i.e. the AJAX request is getting completed without any issue locally/remote but I'm trying to execute the same AJAX request under Cypress test, it's spontaneously providing 500 Server Error.

Comment: Can you show the actual error output and stacktrace?

Comment: @RosenMihaylov, added the image into the question, is this what you were asking?

Comment: Yes it is unflamiliar issue for me, but like this it is more likely someone would be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Two things seem to be indicated by the log

1. the route is not capturing the url (because the error message says so)

   - suggest testing with [Cypress.minimatch](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch.html), perhaps simplify to `url: '/the-ajax-url'`
   - the route should specify `status: 201`, otherwise once the url matches it seems likely to capture the 500 status and set requestStarted true, which is not what you want.
2. `cy.waitUntil()` is not waiting because `requestStarted === true` cannot be true, since the route didn't capture.

   - check out this as an alternative way to retry [cypress xhr request retry ontimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453021/9161752). `cy.waitUntil()` uses recursion under the hood, but it's not entirely clear how to the `until` part works. Going to a simpler recursive function will give you more clarity.